# Android: is this image/page indicator a standard widget?

Tags: android

I would like to make use of something like the 3 circles at the bottom of the apps grid, to switch between images and indicate which image is being viewed.  I can't find any widget like this in the sdk, does it exist or do I have to make a custom component?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not a native widget, but the ViewPager is a native widget that comes with the v4 compatibility pack. All you need then is a way to indicate which page you're on. I'm currently using this project for the TabPageIndicator, but it looks like the CirclePageIndicator would be of use to you:

https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator